# Micro services and .NET using RabbitMQ and OWIN

Tags: rabbitmq, owin, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I found examples of building micro services with .NET using RabbitMQ e.g. [Microservices with C# and RabbitMQ](https://insidethecpu.com/2015/05/22/microservices-with-c-and-rabbitmq/) or using OWIN e.g. [Use OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api).

The goal of the OWIN interface is to decouple server and application, encourage the development of simple modules.

Is it correct that with OWIN you don't need a message queue like RabbitMQ? Or does it make sense to use OWIN and RabbitMQ together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The articles cover two different aspects of creating micro services.

OWIN let's you deploy asp.net applications in a single process, without the necessity for the asp.net runtime or IIS. This makes for a much simpler deployment and scalability. You might consider deploying with Windows containers.

However, as you yourself pointed out, asp.net core let's you do the same thing and has the additional benefit of being cross platform. Polyglot programming is another tenet of micro service based development. With asp.net core you can use docker containers and mix and match all kinds of services: https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker

Rabbitmq let's you introduce asynchronous patterns into your code, loosely connecting your micro services.

Both are arrows in your micro service quiver. A real life application will likely use both approaches.

Comment: Is not asp.net core without OWIN already making it easier to deploy a web server without IIS?

Comment: I've been a little out of the loop on the MS stack, but yes see my amended answer.